# Reversão de Exclusão

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, exclusão

Eu já havia levantado superficialmente [esse tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27424/distribuir-conte%C3%BAdo-uniformemente-em-tabelas-com-php) no chat, mas só uma ou duas pessoas responderam.

Recentemente, vasculhando meu perfil, vi essa pergunta novamente e confesso que fique incomodado com nenhuma atitude aparentemente ter sido tomada então sinalizei o tópico e alguém respondeu sugerindo trazê-lo para cá, no META.

Quando essa pergunta foi postada, na mesma tarde eu montei um exemplo completo demonstrado o uso do Composite que, embora válido e aplicável à pergunta é meio inútil hoje em dia, com tantas ferramentas de templates poderosas e muito mais simples.

Mas não tive a oportunidade de postar pois quando fui fazê-lo, este foi excluído, na minha opinião, por pressão da comunidade (meia dúzia não entendeu e pressionou tanto que o autor excluiu, impedindo àqueles que entenderam de prosseguir).

Nessas circunstâncias, é possível fazer uma moção geral pra reverter a exclusão?

Comment: No meu ver é um problema tão específico que a reversão basicamente só vai servir para você postar sua resposta.

Comment: E em quê isso seria tão diferente de dezenas de tópicos criados e respondidos pela mesma pessoa que visam publicamente "ampliar a base de conhecimentos do site" mas, no fundo, no fundo, simplesmente desejam angariar toneladas de *upvotes*? É claro que é um problema específico, o Marcelo não viria no SOPT postar a dúvida de outra pessoa. Se eu conseguir um votinho que seja, já fico feliz, não tenho perspectivas de fazer minha reputação aumentar estratosfericamente, apenas de ajudar, de verdade.

Comment: não vejo o problema pelo fato de você ter ou não votos, só acho um esforço em demasia por uma pergunta que não justifica. De qq forma, se é importante para você, acabo de dar o voto que falta para desfazer a exclusão, então sinta-se à vontade para postar sua resposta. Creio que mal não vai fazer.

Comment: Vendo o tamanho e o detalhamento da sua resposta, agora entendo a *moção* ;)

Comment: Espero que valha a pena :D

Answer (score 7):

Bom, a "moção" é esta pergunta aqui mesmo :)

Usuários com o privilégio de [acesso às ferramentas de moderador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) podem votar para reverter a exclusão. **Porém**, neste caso específico, eu comentaria em algum post recente do autor da pergunta, perguntando se ele não tem interesse em reverter ele mesmo. Imagino que ele tenha tido um bom motivo para excluir, e talvez não fique muito feliz caso a comunidade desfaça sua decisão.

Em relação à resposta que você preparou, sempre existe a possibilidade de postar uma pergunta você mesmo, acompanhada da resposta. Talvez seja necessário alterar a sua resposta e deixá-la mais genérica – inclusive, uma pergunta mais genérica com uma resposta idem pode ser útil para mais gente.

Comment: Prefiro não fazer isso porque é quase como um spam. Vamos se eu citar o @Marcelo Aymone aqui ele recebe a notificação e opine por ele mesmo. Quanto ao privilégio de voto para reversão, eu já o fiz, tão logo eu recebi poderes para isso, mas não sabia se esse tipo de atitude aparece na fila de análise para outros com o mesmo privilégio pudessem votar.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto mencionar outra pessoa não envolvida aqui infelizmente não gera notificação. A única forma de fazer isso é comentando em alguma publicação que ele teve atividade (seja autoria ou comentário).

Comment: Como disse o @GuilhermeBernal, [o Marcelo não vai receber notificação por ter sido mencionado aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/943), você precisaria mesmo comentar em um post em que ele tenha participado. Mais tarde, você pode excluir o comentário. Não existe fila de análise para reverter exclusão, mas quem tem o privilégio que citei na resposta pode ver uma [lista com as perguntas com votos para desfazer exclusão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last7days).

Comment: Não sabia da existência desse link.

Comment: Em qualquer tela de análise, clique na palavra "Ferramentas" no cabeçalho. @BrunoAugusto

Comment: Legal, ajudaria se ele não fosse cinza >.<

Comment: Prezados, estou acompanhando pelo celular e não entendi exatamente, pois a visualização é mínima, mas logo mais tarde, verifico. Abraço.

Comment: Pessoal, deixo meu voto a favor de reverter(mesmo porque já foi feito), considerando a resposta aplicada pelo Bruno Augusto, que faz uso de design patterns e conceitos interessantes a serem disponibilizados a outros usuários.

O motivo pelo qual exclui a resposta, foi realmente falta de compreensão por boa parte dos colegas que postaram comentários. Bruno Augusto, obrigado pela resposta.